# Why does this greet function not return the accepted value?

Tags: c++, function, struct, variable-assignment

```
#include <string>

struct Person
{
  Person(std::string name) {
  }

  std::string greet(std::string other_name)
  {
    name="Joe";
    return "Hi " + other_name + ", my name is " + name;
  }

  std::string name;
};
```

With the greet function, I want a name (e.g. John) to be returned, however, the function, as it is written, returns nothing. It is blank after the "my name is" string.

How do I properly assign the value of name within the struct, such that I can have a proper return?

Thank you for any nudging in the right direction!

Comment: Its not very clear what the 'proper' return value is. Should it be `Hi X my name is Joe` or something else? At a guess I'd say you want the value passed in to the constructor to be used? It might make your intent clearer if you include a small main function showing how `Person` is being used.

Comment: What compiler do you use? For me, your code works as expected.

Comment: Post a full program (i.e. a main that calls the function) that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: You have a bug in the code you haven't shown. You need to post an [mcve]. I don't understand how this can get up-voted.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, all. This function I am working on is part of an online, interactive program. The main is handled on the server's end, and I am supposed to design the greet function, such that when it is called, a greeting is displayed in the format:

"Hi other_name, my name is name"

However, I am quite the novice and have had little exposure to proper handling and design of data structures. I believe my problem has to do with assigning the name value to something else within the struct, and calling on that new assignment in the function.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not initializing the name field from the parameter in the constructor. i.e. change the constructor to:

```
 #include <string>

    struct Person
    {
      Person(std::string name) : name(name) {} {
    }

    std::string greet(std::string other_name)
    {
      return "Hi " + other_name + ", my name is " + name;
    }

    std::string name;
    };
```

This should solve your problem and will return the desired solution.

Answer (score -1):

try using breakpoints?

i ran the code using g++ with minGW and got the same result, then changed it to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

struct Person
{
  string name;
  Person(string _name) {
      name = _name;
  }

  string greet(string other_name)
  {
    return "Hi " + other_name + ", my name is " + name;
  }

};

int main()
{
    Person person("foo");
    std::cout << person.greet("bar");
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that name is null, but the compiler doesn't give any warnings
this outputs "hello bar, my name is foo" , i compiled myself and got correct result

Comment: Quick correction: `name` is not null. It is default-initialized, and for a `std::string` that means an empty string. And a slight improvement: `Person(string _name): name(_name) {}` initializes `name` with with a `std::string` constructor before entering the body of the constructor. with `name = _name` in the body of the constructor, `name` may first be default constructed and then assigned, basically doing two jobs instead of one.

Comment: Wow, breakpoints...Okay, that seemed to be the problem with my attempt at figuring this out. Could anybody recommend some novice resources for making sure I understand the "little things" of these?

Comment: well you answered your own question, go through it step by step :)
for breakpoints i use gdb
instead of focusing on little things make sure you understand the basics first

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string>

struct Person
{
  Person(std::string _name) {
   name = _name;}

  std::string greet(std::string other_name)
  {

    return "Hi " + other_name + ", my name is " + name;
  }

  std::string name;
};
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer